# Save multi-select drop down ids to the database

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

I want to save multi-select dropdown ids to the database.

blade.php

```
<select name="namedropdown[]" id="namedropdown" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Nothing selected</option>
        @foreach ($tdropdown as $tdrop)
        <option value="{{$tdrop}}">{{$tdrop}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

multi-select dropdown data retrieving function in the controller

```
public function empdata(){
    $tdropdown = DB::table('teams')->pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('employee.create',compact('tdropdown'));
}
```

output of dd($tdropdown)

```
#items: array:3 [
1 => "One"
2 => "Two"
3 => "Three"
]
```

store function in the controller

```
public function empstore(Request $request){
    $employee = new employee();
    $employee->namedropdown = implode(',', $request->input('namedropdown'));

    $employee->save();
}
```

The above mentioned empstore function in the controller helps to save multi-select dropdown names to the database. But I want to **save multi-select dropdown ids to the database.**

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: the value of the select option should be the id, not the name

Comment: First your foreach has to change to `@foreach ($tdropdown as $id => $tdrop)
        <option value="{{$id}}">{{$tdrop}}</option>
        @endforeach` What do you have after doing this?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked for me. -@lagbox

I want to save those **multi-select dropdown ids** in another table with many to many relationship. Hope your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410546/multi-select-dropdown-with-many-to-many-relation